# Lambdas and putIfAbsent

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14851827/823393) where the code demonstrating use of the `putIfAbsent` method of `ConcurrentMap` read:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicLong> ();

public long addTo(String key, long value) {
  // The final value it became.
  long result = value;
  // Make a new one to put in the map.
  AtomicLong newValue = new AtomicLong(value);
  // Insert my new one or get me the old one.
  AtomicLong oldValue = map.putIfAbsent(key, newValue);
  // Was it already there? Note the deliberate use of '!='.
  if ( oldValue != newValue ) {
    // Update it.
    result = oldValue.addAndGet(value);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The main downside of this approach is that you have to create a new object to put into the map whether it will be used or not. This can have significant effect if the object is heavy.

It occurred to me that this would be an opportunity to use Lambdas. I have not downloaded Java 8 n'or will I be able to until it is official (company policy) so I cannot test this but would something like this be valid and effective?

```
public long addTo(String key, long value) {
  return map.putIfAbsent( key, () -> new AtomicLong(0) ).addAndGet(value);
}
```

I am hoping to use the lambda to delay the evaluation of the `new AtomicLong(0)` until it is actually determined that it should be created because it does not exist in the map.

As you can see this is much more succinct and functional.

Essentially I suppose my questions are:

1. Will this work?
2. Or have I completely misinterpreted lambdas?
3. Might something like this work one day?

Comment: How are you not able to download Java 8 and test it yourself? Does your company prevent you from installing anything (even for evaluation purposes) on your work computer? How about trying it on your personal one then?

Comment: @SimonLehmann - BTW - After your comment I installed Java 8 and not only did it not have Lambdas (there was an extra I was supposed to install but didn't get around to it) but DBVisualiser stopped working - so I removed it. Sorry. Perhaps next year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE 2015-08-01**

The `computeIfAbsent` method as described below has indeed been [added to Java SE 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). The semantics appear to be very close to the pre-release version.

In addition, `computeIfAbsent`, along with a whole pile of new default methods, has been added to the `Map` interface. Of course, maps in general can't support atomic updates, but the new methods add considerable convenience to the API.

---

What you're trying to do is quite reasonable, but unfortunately it doesn't work with the current version of `ConcurrentMap`. An enhancement is on the way, however. The new version of the concurrency library includes `ConcurrentHashMapV8` which contains a new method `computeIfAbsent`. This pretty much allows you to do exactly what you're looking to do. Using this new method, your example could be rewritten as follows:

```
public long addTo(String key, long value) {
    return map.computeIfAbsent( key, () -> new AtomicLong(0) ).addAndGet(value);
}
```

For further information about the `ConcurrentHashMapV8`, see Doug Lea's [initial announcement thread](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2011-August/008176.html) on the concurrency-interest mailing list. Several messages down the thread is [a followup message](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2011-August/008193.html) that shows an example very similar to what you're trying to do. (Note however the old lambda syntax. That message was from August 2011 after all.) And here is [recent javadoc](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166edocs/jsr166e/ConcurrentHashMapV8.html#computeIfAbsent%28K,%20jsr166e.ConcurrentHashMapV8.Fun%29) for `ConcurrentHashMapV8`.

This work is intended to be integrated into Java 8, but it hasn't yet as far as I can see. Also, this is still a work in progress, names and specs may change, etc.

Comment: Thank you - except for the fact that it's going to be called `ConcurrentHashMapV8`. What a horrifying idea!!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's still going to be called CHMV8 by the time it's actually integrated into Java 8. I suspect Doug Lea calls it CHMV8 so it can be used at the same time as CHM in apps, tests, benchmarks for comparison purposes. Lea does say it's intended to be a replacement for CHM.

Comment: With JDK8 API the OPs problem can be solved even easier with `Map.merge`. Wrote an answer about this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not as easy as that. There are two main problems with the approach you've sketched out:
1. The type of the map would need to change from `Map<String, AtomicLong>` to `Map<String, AtomicLongFunction>` (where `AtomicLongFunction` is some function interface that has a single method that takes no arguments and returns an `AtomicLong`).
2. When you retrieve the element from the map you'd need to apply the function each time to get the `AtomicLong` out of it. This would result in creating a new instance each time you retrieve it, which is not likely what you wanted.

The idea of having a map that runs a function on demand to fill up missing values is a good one, though, and in fact Google's Guava library has a map that does exactly that; see their [MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html). In fact that code would benefit from Java 8 lambda expressions: instead of

```
   ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
       .concurrencyLevel(4)
       .weakKeys()
       .makeComputingMap(
           new Function<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph apply(Key key) {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

you'd be able to write

```
   ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
       .concurrencyLevel(4)
       .weakKeys()
       .makeComputingMap((Key key) -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

or

```
   ConcurrentMap<Key, Graph> graphs = new MapMaker()
       .concurrencyLevel(4)
       .weakKeys()
       .makeComputingMap(this::createExpensiveGraph);
```

Comment: Somehow I just knew my solution was far more simple that it would end up being. So I would effectively be adding the **lambda** to the map rather than the **result** of the lambda ... oh well.

Answer (score 2):

`AtomicLong` is not really a heavy object. For heavier objects I would consider a lazy proxy and provide a lambda to that one to create the object if needed.

```
class MyObject{
    void doSomething(){}
}

class MyLazyObject extends MyObject{
    Funktion create;
    MyLazyObject(Funktion create){
        this.create = create;
    }
    MyObject instance;
    MyObject getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = create.apply();
        return instance;
    }
    @Override void doSomething(){getInstance().doSomething();}
}

public long addTo(String key, long value) {
  return map.putIfAbsent( key, new MyLazyObject( () -> new MyObject(0) ) );
}
```

Comment: I used an `AtomicLong` as an example place-holder, I was indeed thinking in terms of much heavier objects. This looks effective but there's an awful lot of stuff going on to implement the laziness which is supposed to be innate in a lambda anyway.

Comment: Using the Guava library seems easier. But writing lazy objects makes you independent form Map implementations.
You could also create a generic InvocationHandler that would delegate all method invocations, see  [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html). But you'r right, that would be a real overkill in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Note that using Java 8 `ConcurrentHashMap` it's completely unnecessary to have `AtomicLong` values. You can safely use [ConcurrentHashMap.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Long> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();

public long addTo(String key, long value) {
    return map.merge(key, value, Long::sum);
}
```

It's much simpler and also significantly faster.