# Java CHM synchronisation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

Following up on this question ([Java thread safety - multiple atomic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620240/java-thread-safety-multiple-atomic-operations)), I don't want to add more questions to it, but now I have this doubt:

```
private final Map<String, Set<String>> data = Maps.newConcurrentMap();

... then in a method ...

if (data.containsKey("A")) {
    data.get("A").add("B");
}
```

It should be something like this:

```
synchronized(data) {
    if (data.containsKey("A")) {
        data.get("A").add("B");
    }
}
```

In order to be thread-safe. Is that correct?

So operations are atomic, but combining them would require synchronisation, is that right? At that point, would it make sense to just use a simple HashMap instead of a concurrent one, as we're manually handling sync?

Is there any method in CHM to make this work atomically?

Comment: One advantage over simple HashMap is that CHM still does not require synchronization for the readers.

Comment: Please also show the code that modifies the CHM. The above code is read-only (only calls `get` and `containsKey`) as far as the Map is concerned.

Comment: @Thilo just imagine the `put` method is used by multiple threads. Anyway what I'm interested in is if I need that `synchronised` in order to make it thread-safe. Also, if there's any construct in CHM to help me avoid that sync, and do a `map.addValueIfKeyPresent` (I know that method doesn't exist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you check if the map containsKey before using ConcurrentMap's putIfAbsent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752194/should-you-check-if-the-map-containskey-before-using-concurrentmaps-putifabsent)

Comment: If there is no `remove` method, you maybe don't need synchronization code at all. Adding something to a `Set` twice is a no-op anyway. Is that `Set` thread-safe?

Comment: Isnt computeIfPresent made for this?

Comment: @Thilo there is other threads removing, unfortunately... So I guess I do need a CHM. Yes, the Set is thread safe too. Is my code then thread-safe without requiring `synchronised`?

Comment: May I ask what kind of set you're using that's thread safe?

Comment: @shmosel I'm using this: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newConcurrentHashSet--

Comment: You can use AtomicReference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, you might want to use [`computeIfPresent` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) of `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
data.computeIfPresent("A", (k, v) -> { v.add("B"); return v; } );
```

From the javadocs:

> If the value for the specified key is present, attempts to compute a new mapping given the key and its current mapped value. **The entire method invocation is performed atomically**.

So there's no need for explicit synchronization.

Comment: That's great, so there is a method in CHM for this.... Great! Still I have the question: if that method didn't exist, would my first code be OK? Or would I need the second one with explicit sync?

Comment: Usually `computeIfAbsent()` is what you want. It initializes the value if it's absent, then returns it. But it's not entirely clear what you need here.

Comment: @Will I think you'd need to synchronize explicitly, but the best approach would be the one suggested by @shmosel: `data.computeIfAbsent("A", k -> Sets.newConcurrentHashSet()).add("B");`

Comment: I'm worried about the (mis)use of `computeIfPresent()` to mutate the value instead of replacing it. I'm not sure if the atomicity guarantee would still hold true in this case.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner: `computeIfAbsent` will add a new Set. The original code only added to an existing set.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner why is that better? I don't want to do anything if the element is absent, I only want to do it if the element is present. @shmosel why do you say it's better to do `computeIfAbsent`?

Comment: @shmosel: The atomicity guarantee still holds, but it only extends to the Map. The Set needs to be threadsafe as well (no matter how).

Comment: The way I'm adding to the map (using multiple threads): `data.put("A", Sets. newConcurrentHashSet());`. Makes sense?

Comment: @Will You are OK, disregard my comment. It's just that I've always used `computeIfAbsent` and have never needed to use `computeIfPresent`, so it looks a little bit awkward to me. But if that's your use case, then go ahead with it!

Comment: @Will: You probably want `putIfAbsent` if you add from multiple threads. Otherwise you might overwrite an existing (and populated) set.

Comment: @Thilo I was about to say exactly that

Comment: Guys thanks a lot to all of you, I've learnt a lot. I think this is the right answer, so I'll accept it. But thanks a lot @Thilo for your great help, I really appreciate it! Same goes for @shmosel!

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronised(data) {
    if (data.containsKey("A")) {
        data.get("A").add("B");
    }
}
```

You probably need to show more code.

Looking only at this, the only possible issue is that someone removes the Set found at `"A"` after your `if` check.  **If you don't ever remove map entries you need no synchronization at all.**

If you do remove map entries concurrently, you could use `computeIfPresent` to arrive at the updated map.

You could also do

```
Set<String> set = data.get("A");
if (set != null) set.add("B");
```

Since you are not actually producting a new Set, I find this more idiomatic than `computeIfPresent` (which should compute a new value).

Note that you need to make all these Sets thread-safe as well.

Comment: `containsKey()` and `get()` are still redundant operations. I would do `Set<String> set = data.get("A"); if (set != null) set.add("B");`... Beat me to it :)

Comment: @shmosel: Me too. Seems better than `computeIfPresent` as well (because no new value is computed, but the existing value is mutated).